# How to install chef extension via azure sdk

Tags: java, azure, cloud, chef-infra

I need to create deployment with role that contains Chef extension via Java Azure SDK. I have next code for setting extension parameters, but it doesn't work.

As an example I use next material in Python http://blogs.msdn.com/b/shwetasblogs/archive/2015/02/19/creating-deployment-amp-customizing-linux-vms-with-python-amp-chef-part-2.aspx

```
private void withExtension(Role role) {
        ArrayList<ResourceExtensionReference> references = new ArrayList<ResourceExtensionReference>();
        ResourceExtensionReference reference = new ResourceExtensionReference();
        reference.setReferenceName("LinuxChefClient");
        reference.setVersion("11.*");
        reference.setPublisher("Chef.Bootstrap.WindowsAzure");
        reference.setName("LinuxChefClient");

        ResourceExtensionParameterValue publicConfig = new ResourceExtensionParameterValue();
        publicConfig.setType("Public");
        publicConfig.setKey("PublicParams");
        String value = "{\n" +
                "  \"client_rb\": \"chef_server_url \\\"https://<chefServerUri>\\\"\\nnode_name \\\"<vmName>\\\"\\nvalidation_key \\\"/etc/chef/validation.pem\\\"\\nlog_location  \\\"/etc/chef/client.log\\\"\\nlog_level  :info\\njson_attribs \\\"/etc/chef/role.json\\\"\",\n" +
                "  \"run_list\": [\"role[base]\"]\n" +
                "}";
        publicConfig.setValue(value);


        ResourceExtensionParameterValue privateConfig = new ResourceExtensionParameterValue();
        privateConfig.setType("Private");
        privateConfig.setKey("PrivateParams");
        privateConfig.setValue("{ \"validation_key\": \"" + VALIDATION_PEM + "\" }");

        ArrayList<ResourceExtensionParameterValue> parameterValues = new ArrayList<ResourceExtensionParameterValue>();


    parameterValues.add(publicConfig);
            parameterValues.add(privateConfig);
reference.setResourceExtensionParameterValues(parameterValues);

        references.add(reference);

        role.setResourceExtensionReferences(references);
}
```

Comment: Two questions: 1.what's error did you encountered? 2.It seems that you didn't use base64 to encrypt your private and public configuration. Did you try to change it?

Answer (score 0):

It seems that you do not encrypt the value of `privateConfig` and `publicConfig`. As this [official document description(Request body part)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn169558.aspx), before setting value, we need encrypt those values:

```
    <PublicConfiguration>
base-64-encoded-xsd-for-extension-public-configuration
</PublicConfiguration>
      <PrivateConfiguration>
base-64-encoded-xsd-for-extension-private-configuration
</PrivateConfiguration>
```

Please try to add this code into your project:

```
value=Base64.encode(value.getBytes(Charset.forName("UTF-8")));
```

By the way, please share more error information if the above code don't work.

Comment: Azure SDK for Java - encrypt values internally. If change extension for WIndows machine, it works fine, but for Linux (Ubuntu) - nothing happens. Also it doesn't work via Azure Powershell (CustomScriptForLinux) 
http://azure.microsoft.com/blog/2014/08/20/automate-linux-vm-customization-tasks-using-customscript-extension/

Answer (score 0):

I am not able to add the comment, so asking my questions in Reply -

1. What is the error that you see?
2. Is your VM getting created successfully?

George, please answer these questions so that I can help you better. By the way, you can check the blog - http://blogs.msdn.com/b/azureossds/archive/2015/09/08/accessing-vm-extensions-like-chef-using-azure-sdk-for-java-programmatically.aspx

for using Azure sdk for Java to access the extensions. You will have to modify the code to set the extension reference in order to create a new one.

Hope this helps !!